# Order of Execution when creating a case from email-to-case

Tags: apex, email2case

Could anyone tell what is the order of execution, when there is a case created from the email-to-case configuration?

I am in the process of differentiating a case to assign a status to it. AFAI tested the sourceId is populated when the case is created via Email-To-Case.

What's the order of execution on sourceId assignment in a Case?

In the before insert trigger the case sourceId is always null. What's the order of execution as I couldn't find it anywhere on the document?

I assume,

When sending an email to the Email Service Address,

1. Create an Email Message.
2. Create a Case.
3. Update the ParentCaseId on Email Message
4. Update the SourceId on Case.

I was trying to do the below check in the Case before insert trigger, but it didn't work as expected,

```
if (newCase.sourceId != null) {
    newCase.Status = 'In Progress';
}
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: the Case is created before the EmalMessage

Comment: So, it makes sense that the sourceId is null.

Comment: i've not specifically tracked when sourceId is set -- writing debug statements in a Case trigger and turning debug on for the E2C user will let you know when it is set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is follows,

```
The case is created.
The email message is created with the parentId.
The case sourceId will be populated.
```

Comment: So case is created before insert and sourceId populated after insert? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can see the behavior by just having a debug statement.