# Email-To-Case Order of Execution question

Tags: marketing-cloud, email2case

I'm working on an org where Marketing Cloud RMM is causing an issue with Salesforce Email-To-Case. Here's a summary of the issue:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfTxUAJ/enable-marketingcloud-rrm-to-create-emailtocase-in-servicecloud

As a workaround, we're trying to implement the fix described in this article: https://forceforthought.com/2022/07/how-to-fix-forwarded-rmm-replies-flow/
Basically the article describes a Flowthat modifies EmailMessage.FromAddress in order to enable Email-To-Case to match new Cases to the correct Contact.

After trying out the Flow solution, it looks like Salesforce is executing the Flow *after* Email-To-Case (not before as we had expected). We also tried implementing this solution using a before insert trigger on EmailMessage and a before insert trigger on Case. In all scenarios, it looks like our automation (whether flow or apex) is executing *after* Email-To-Case.

Can anyone confirm when Email-To-Case runs in the Salesforce order of execution? Does anyone have any recommendations for a workaround to our Marketing Cloud Rmm / Email-To-Case issue? As a final resort, we were thinking about creating a custom email service in place of standard Email-To-Case. This custom email service would execute the logic described in the article above and also generate the Case record.  But ideally we'd like to find a solution that leverages standard Email-To-Case functionality.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388596/order-of-execution-when-creating-a-case-from-email-to-case and https://architect.salesforce.com/1/asset/immutable/s/e6cf2ac/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png